# Teaspoon fails hard after Rails update 4.2.9 to 4.2.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, sprockets, teaspoon

Teaspoon has broken after update Rails from 4.2.9 to 4.2.10. Nothing else has changed with project.

Here's the failure when test suite hits teaspoon:

```
Starting the Teaspoon server...
[33337] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[33337] * Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.3.3-p222), codename: Russell's Teapot
[33337] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[33337] * Environment: test
[33337] * Process workers: 2
[33337] * Preloading application
[33337] * Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:63120
[33337] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[33337] - Worker 0 (pid: 33351) booted, phase: 0
[33337] - Worker 1 (pid: 33352) booted, phase: 0
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:63120/teaspoon/default
Error: ActionView::Template::Error: Asset was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( support/bind-poly.self.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server
/Users/meltemi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:363:in `raise_unless_precompiled_asset'
```

Run just Teaspoon with `rake teaspoon` (as opposed to `rake` for default suite which `default [:teaspoon]` is a part) it fails a little differently:

```
...
Teaspoon running default suite at http://127.0.0.1:63120/teaspoon/default
Failed to load: http://127.0.0.1:63120/teaspoon/default?reporter=Console
rake teaspoon failed
[33352] ! Detected parent died, dying
```

Here's the line from `lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb` that it's tripping over:

```
def raise_unless_precompiled_asset(path)
  raise Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled.new(path) if @check_precompiled_asset && !precompiled?(path)
end
```

Not much in the diff between Rails `4.2.9...4.2.10`. Hoping one of you smarter people can catch what might be triggering this. Seems like it might be related to asset pipeline or routes to vendored gems...but that's just a guess!?!
https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v4.2.9...v4.2.10

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck (so far) with the suggested monkey patch [here](https://github.com/jejacks0n/teaspoon/issues/443#issuecomment-168333568).

I added this to the bottom of my `taspoon_env.rb` file:

```
# https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon/issues/443
module RaiseUnlessPrecompiledFixer
  def raise_unless_precompiled_asset(path)
    super unless path.split('.')[-2] == 'self'
  end
end
Sprockets::Rails::HelperAssetResolvers::Environment.send(:prepend,RaiseUnlessPrecompiledFixer)
```